# Finding a not exact match in a list of lists

Tags: python

Let's say I have a list of lists like

```py
    new_list=[[1,2,3],
              [9,1,6],
              [7,3,4]]
```

I'd like to do something like

```py
    n=new_list.index([7,:,4])
```

and I'd like

```py
n==2
```

because indeed,

```py
new_list[2]==[7,3,4]
```

I hope this example makes my point, I want to find if a list of lists contains a certain list without especifying the full list to be found.

Comment: List `index` does not support partial match like you need. One way of solving is: `[i for i, x in enumerate(new_list) if x[0] == 7 and x[-1] == 4]`. Not sure if this will help in all your scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can define a partial "match" function where `None` matches all and then use `next` to find the first partial match (similar to what `index` does, finding only the first match):

```
pMatch = lambda l1, l2: all([x[0] == x[1] or x[0] == None for x in zip(l1, l2)]) 

# examples of partial matches
pMatch([1, 2, None], [1, 2, 3])                                                                                                                                                             
# True
pMatch([1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3])                                                                                                                                                                
# False

new_list = [[1, 2, 3], [9, 1, 6], [7, 3, 4]]
l = [7, None, 4]

next(i for i in range(len(new_list)) if pMatch(l, new_list[i]))    
# 2
```

In one line:

```
next(i for i in range(len(new_list)) if all([x[0]==x[1] or x[0]==None for x in zip(l, new_list[i])])) 
# 2
```

(assuming that all lists have the same length)

Answer (score 0):

Approach this in two steps:

1. Define a function that compares a list against a partial list. You can use `None` instead of the colon from your example.

   ```
   def matches(pattern, candidate):
     # check that pattern and candidate are lists of same length
     # loop over all indices i:
     #   if pattern[i] is not None, candidate[i] must be equal
   ```
2. Then loop over the list of lists, calling the function from 1. on each element, until you find an item that matches or the list ends.

Answer (score 0):

This function should do it (quick&dirty):

```
>>> new_list=[[1,2,3],
...           [9,1,6],
...           [7,3,4]]
>>> 
>>> def find(lst, members):
...   for i in range(len(lst)):
...     match=True
...     for j in members:
...       if j not in lst[i]:
...         match=False
...         break
...     if match:
...       return i
...   return None
... 
>>> find(new_list, [2, 3])
0
>>> find(new_list, [3, 1])
0
>>> find(new_list, [2, 4])
>>> find(new_list, [7, 4])
2
>>> find(new_list, [7])
2
>>> find(new_list, [8, 9])
```